# Code example: How to get transaction hash before sending transaction

Tags: transactions, ethers.js, raw-transaction, hash, receipts

I know their might be examples online, but they do not really solve my issue.

So let us say I have the code below:

```
  this.factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(
    "factoryContractAddress",
    "factoryContractABI",
    signer
  );

  this.factoryContract.createChild()// how can I get transaction hash instead of waiting for it inside the "then(){}" callback?
    .then(()=>{/*do things here**/});
    .catch(()=>{/*do things here**/});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "before sending transaction"?! Before user confirm it or being mined?!

Comment: Before it is mined. I mean just after it is signed by the user but before sending it to the blockchain to be mined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found what you want But not sure.

```
async function creatChildContract(){
   tx = await this.factoryContract.createChild();
   tx.hash //returns hash of the transaction which user just signed.
}
```

Comment: No, I do not want to await for the transaction to be mined.

Comment: No, this `await` is waiting for user to sign the transaction, not transaction to be mined!

Comment: My bad. You are right. :) Thank you.

Comment: No problem, my friend. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an answer to my problem:

```
async function creatChildContract(){
    this.factoryContract.createChild()
    .then((log)=>{
        console.log(log.hash);
        // here you can access the transaction hash before it is mined
        // you do not have to wait, once the transaction is confirmed, the hash is available.
    });
    .catch(()=>{/*do things here**/})
})
```